# Errors using std::for_each lambda function

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, wt

I have a little problem and I can't figure out why this code doesn't work:

```
std::for_each(users.begin(), users.end(), [](Wt::WString u)
{
    std::cout << "ilosc: " << users.size() << std::endl;
    userBox_->addItem(u);
});
```

Errors that I get while compiling:

```
GameWidget.cpp: In lambda function:
GameWidget.cpp:352:30: error: 'users' is not captured
GameWidget.cpp:353:4: error: 'this' was not captured for this lambda function
GameWidget.cpp: In member function 'virtual void GameWidget::updateUsers()':
GameWidget.cpp:354:3: warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
GameWidget.cpp:354:4: error: no matching function for call to 'for_each(std::set<Wt::WString>::iterator, std::set<Wt::WString>::iterator, GameWidget::updateUsers()::<lambda(Wt::WString)>)'
GameWidget.cpp:354:4: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/algorithm:63:0,
                 from GameWidget.h:11,
                 from GameWidget.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:4436:5: note: template<class _IIter, class _Funct> _Funct std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct)
GameWidget.cpp:354:4: error: template argument for 'template<class _IIter, class _Funct> _Funct std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct)' uses local type 'GameWidget::updateUsers()::<lambda(Wt::WString)>'
GameWidget.cpp:354:4: error:   trying to instantiate 'template<class _IIter, class _Funct> _Funct std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct)'
```

I am using `gcc 4.7.3`, so probably C++11 support is available for my compiler.

`userBox_` is a collection and `BOOST_FOREACH` works properly for this code:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(Wt::WString i, users)
{
    std::cout << "ilosc: " << users.size() << std::endl;
    userBox_->addItem(i);
}
```

Thanks for any answer, I'm so curious why is that.

Comment: Did you try `[&](Wt::WString u) { ... }`?

Comment: And compiling with `-std=c++11` like the error tells you to?

Comment: In addition to the above comments, you probably meant to use `u.size();` also.

Comment: @chris: `[enabled by default]` seems to indicate that this warning is not the problem?

Comment: @paxdiablo, That means the warning is enabled by default, as least from my experiences. Certain parts of GCC warnings can be a little misleading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The lambda you've written does not capture any context variables. To do this, the easiest is to add `&` to the lambda's capture list. This will capture all context variables by reference and you'll be able to access them within the lambda.

```
std::for_each(users.begin(), users.end(), [&](Wt::WString u)
{
    std::cout << "ilosc: " << users.size() << std::endl;
    userBox_->addItem(u);
});
```

I don't understand why you're printing `users.size()` within the loop, because it looks like the output is going to be the same every iteration. If you move that outside the loop, and want more fine grained control over what the lambda captures, you can modify the capture list to only capture the `this` pointer. This will let you access the member variable `userBox_`.

```
std::cout << "ilosc: " << users.size() << std::endl;
std::for_each(users.begin(), users.end(), [this](Wt::WString u)
{
    userBox_->addItem(u);
});
```

MSDN has an excellent article explaining the [lambda expression syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293603.aspx) in great detail.

Finally, in your case, there's no need for `std::for_each` and a lambda. It would be a lot more succinct to use a range based `for` loop to add the items to the collection.

```
for( auto const& u: users ) {
  userBox_->addItem(u);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for asnwer! Missing & and c11 flag help to properly build code. As you've written users.size() does not have sense in this example, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you needed to know is in the errors you received.

You told the lambda, explicitly, not to capture anything, by using "[]", which means the only variables it has access to inside the function body are parameters and globals.

It doesn't matter what type userBox_ is, it's a member variable, so the lambda needs to capture "this".

Lastly, you're passing by value, which means you're going to duplicate each and every Wt::WString. You might want instead to use

```
std::for_each(users.begin(), users.end(), [&](const Wt::WString& u) {
...
});
```

The "&" captures by reference and will capture "this" for you.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Answer (score 0):

Capturing the variable users means declaring your lambda as:

```
    [users](Wt::WString u){...}
```

which will pass `users` as a read-only variable.

To be able to modify `users`, you need to declare your lambda as:

```
    [&users](Wt::WString u){...}
```